# MobaXterm - ssh to Linux server with gnome, set DISPLAY, "Connection refused"

Tags: connection, mobaxterm

```
ubuntu@dsps-pi-k8s:~$ export DISPLAY=slapa:0.0
ubuntu@dsps-pi-k8s:~$ startx

/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg.wrap: Only console users are allowed to run the X server
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console.
```

But I can see MobaXterm listening on port 6000, the usual X Display server port, and it's not a firewall problem, since: -

```
ubuntu@dsps-pi-k8s:~$ telnet slapa 6000
Trying 192.168.1.237...
Connected to slapa.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> quit
Connection closed.
```

I'm sure this is what I used to do with HummingBird Exceed and other X servers before.

Comment: MobaXTerm sets your display variable automatically (at least it does for me).

Answer (score 0):

`startx` is the wrong tool here, as its purpose is to start X clients **and an X server.** You don't need that – the whole point of setting $DISPLAY was so that your programs would use an *existing* X display on another system, whereas "startx" always tries to launch a new one. (Usually it tries to start Xorg for rendering on the SSH server's monitor, which isn't going to work via SSH even if that were what you wanted.)

As you already have an X display server available (via $DISPLAY), you should be starting *only* the X client apps. For many programs this can be done without any special tools; you just run `xterm &` or `firefox &` through the SSH connection.

(To start an entire GNOME session you'd run `dbus-run-session gnome-session &`, although I don't expect GNOME to run all that well over networked X11 – you'll probably need to use Xvnc instead.)

To start the same X clients that startx would've started, you could manually run the `~/.xinitrc` script, or `/etc/X11/xinitrc` if you don't have a custom one.